# replace large image with a different one when thumbnail is clicked (gallery)

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hey guys. My aim was to create myself a personal portfolio site for a new hobby, photography.

At the moment everything is in place. (This can be seen [here](http://scrapbook.beauaugust.co.uk/).)

The problem is, try as I might, I can't get the image to replace in CSS. I mucked around for ages attempting to move the images etc, but it just failed miserably. My new plan is to use jQuery.

Here's where I need your guy's help. I have no knowledge of jQuery, and I need the large image to be replaced with the one in the thumbnail when it's clicked. Kinda like a button. Is that possible, and can you help me? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could try some jQuery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.gallery img').click(function() {
        var img = $(this).attr('src');
        $('.content img').attr('src', img);
    });
});
```

Obviously you will have to include the [jQuery core](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery), normally within the `<head>` tag's of your pages:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Take a look at the [**demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Scoobler/BYYDe/1/)

---

What might be another nice touch, for your thumbnails, make the cursor into a pointer *(make the thumbnails look click-able)* - either directly with CSS, or let jQuery do it for you:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.gallery img').click(function() {
        var img = $(this).attr('src');
        $('.content img').attr('src', img);
    }).each(function() {
        $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
    });
});
```

Take a look at the [**demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Scoobler/BYYDe/2/)

Comment: @Beau_August Note that Scoobler and my scripts do the same thing except his does the image change on a `click` and mine does it on a `hover`.

Comment: @Chris W. - TV is rubbish tonight :D _(see the update for proof haha)_ +1 for the hover!!

Comment: That is simply gorgeous. Thanks guys. I totally understand now. That's amazing. Just on a side note ~ How does the page actually look to you? Do you think it's ok?

And sorry for the spam, do you think hover or click would be nicer?

Comment: @Scoobler Hahaha: "Bored? Why not write javascript for strangers on the internet for free?" I guess there are worse things to do with one's free time.

Comment: @Beau_August I think the page looks great--very professional looking! you should be aware that some of the CSS you are using to scale the images and shadow on hover, i.e. `-webkit-transform`, `-moz-box-shadow`, etc., won't work on older browsers. Probably a majority of browsers on the internet currently.

Comment: Yeah I know. I decided stuff Internet Explorer, I'm sorry to say. SOME of the effects and styles do, but the majority don't. I'll get round to at least cleaning it up in IE eventually, just not now. Thanks for all your help, I'll know where to go if (WHEN) I need it again!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll definitely need to use Javascript/jQuery to do what you want to do.

Include the jQuery script on your page between the `<head>` tags.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
```

Then this simple function should do what you need to do...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.img img').hover(function() {
    $img = $(this)
    $('.content img').attr('src',$img.attr('src'))
});
});
```

You should really learn more about Javascript/jQuery in general it's a very cool technology and a good skill to have.

Check out [jQuery tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials).

Comment: This is great! Do I just copy and paste that multiple times for the multiple thumbnails, modifying as needed? Maybe I'm being naive here.

Comment: No, no, it will work for all images because the "selector" `.img img` refers to all `<img>` elements inside of an HTML element with a class of `.img` (which is what all of your thumbnails are).

Comment: Oh I see. Well I hope you know that you've inspired me to get on my way with jQuery. I did plan on learning it...but wow, that's so simple yet gorgeous. Exactly what I needed. You guys are all stars, I love this website.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use JQuery. Don't use any JavaScript at all. It's like overkill when the effect you're after is pretty straightforward with just pure CSS2. Take a look at the NOT SUITABLE FOR WORK site:

http://www.simple-nude.com/nude-photos.html

and notice what happens when you hover over any of the thumbs. Something like that seems just what you want. I don't think there's any JavaScript anywhere on that site. Yes, I'm crochety and old-fashioned, but I always prefer the least JS possible.

-- pete

Minimum JS is my crusade, in fact. The worst is simple, easy links implemented with JS! Bah!

Comment: Thanks Pete. Only problem is...it messes with CSS3. I did have something similar to that, see (http://scrapbook.beauaugust.co.uk/a/)

But the problem was it kept messing everything up. The scale webkit was screwing with it. I think jQuery is the way to go

Comment: First of all, have an upvote for introducing naked women into a discussion on the superfluous use of Javascript in webpages. ;) Secondly I don't think that this is an instance of 'unnecessary' use of javascript. While I agree in general people fall back to jQuery waaaaaay more often than they should when all they really need is some more thoughtful CSS, but I think in this case it makes for cleaner and simpler code to dynamically alter the large image.

Comment: @B, yes, your /a page is almost perfect! How do you mean "it messes with CSS3?" Well, if you've decided on JQ then it's a dead issue, but still I'm interested in what you mean. Thanks!

Comment: @Chris: "cleaner and simpler": yeah, maybe so. But how can JQuery contribute to the new cleaner and simpler concept? Why not just JS "img.style.width/height=x/y"? Same for position? Not arguing, just interested.

Comment: Basically, I had it set so that when you hover over the image, it would move it across to where the "main" area is. But when I hovered over a thumbnail, the scale effect continued on the side. It also kept pushing elements about. I'm new to CSS I won't deny, but it really was a pain. And this jQuery is fantastic. I like the idea of using CSS as much as I can, but I had reached the endpoint. And how do I "Upvote" you all? You guys have been so helpful!

Comment: @B, if you got as far as you did (with your /a page) while you're still new to CSS, I'd say you did spectacularly well. CSS IS a huge pain, what with its many exception cases, its peculiar, idiosyncratic  behavior, and its uneven and sometimes illogical support in different browsers. The endpoint usually comes quickly. I think to upvote comments, you hover near the left margin of the comment and you'll see an uparrow, which you can press. And thanks.

Comment: @Pete Good point! JS can certainly handle this task on its own. I think both of us want the most 'elegant' solution. But to you elegance comes from not having to load an external javascript library. To me elegance comes from jQuery's compact CSS-like selectors and its guarantee (almost) of cross-browser compatibility. I really think it's an issue of preference.

Comment: @Chris, I was totally bamboozled by the number of frameworks around when I started JS a couple of months ago; and also by the strong opinions pro and con in the community. So I never did settle on a framework, and now I'm stuck hand coding functions that would have come for free. So imo the issue is one of my envy, jealousy, and general pig-headedness :-)

Answer (score 0):

Anyone for a no conflict version of this for 1.5.1 ... I have a similar thumb opening into a main image working ok in dreamweaver with JQ 1.2.3 but when loaded into Joomla running JQ 1.5.1 it don't work. Code below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(".tmbimage a").click(function(){
    var largePath = jQuery(this).attr("href");
    var largeAlt = jQuery(this).attr("title");      
    jQuery("#mainimg").attr({ src: largePath, alt: largeAlt });     
}); 
});
</script>
```